# Ocultar artículos de una categoría en la página principal de woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Lo que pretendo es ocultar de la página principal de la tienda todos los artículos que pertenezcan a la categoría "Outlet".

La pregunta es ¿Cómo quito de la query los artículos que pertenezcan a la categoría Outlet de la página principal de la tienda?

He intentado lo siguiente sin éxito:

```
function wo_ocultar_outlet( $q, $instance ) {

if( is_shop() || is_page('shop') ) { //No se mostrarán en estas páginas
    $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );

    $tax_query[] = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
           'field'    => 'slug',
           'terms'    => array( 'outlet' ), // Categorías de productos
           'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    );  

    $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
  }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'wo_ocultar_outlet', 10, 2 );
```

También he probado ya en última instancia la instalación del plugin Woo Shortcodes Kit v 1.8.6 y tampoco funciona. Tiene un apartado para ocultar hasta 3 categorías de la página principal de la tienda, pero no obtuve éxito. El theme que estoy utilizando es Lebe (https://themeforest.net/item/lebe-multipurpose-woocommerce-theme/23157704)